# What are these stones?

Tags: dessert, food-identification

I am a fan of some YouTube channel, and back in 2018, he posted this video: [Slav snacks - Slav party tutorial](https://youtu.be/zjgul0TDvRg?t=418) and I really want to try these foods because I'm an Asian.

In timestamp 7:00, he shows off these stones, which are sugar-covered. I'm certain that since this is slav, it is hard to exactly figure out what the stones are.

Search for "sugar-covered stones" and you won't find the similar dessert. What exactly are these given "stones"?

Comment: Not sure what kind they use in slavic countries, but there are a variety of "candy stones" made throughout the world. They are often filled with chocolate, chewy candy (similar to skittles) or something similar to the inside of a jelly bean.

Comment: I almost didn't click on the video link, but I'm so, so glad I did. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image, they look like [jelly beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelly_bean) (or in Serbian, [dželi bins](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%BEeli_Bins)) to me, based on the size, colour (including the slightly mottled pattern which tends to indicate better-quality jelly beans) and shine. The comment 'inside is a mystery' sounds to me like a clear reference to the fact that jelly beans often come in a variety of flavours, and it's not always easy to tell from the colour what the flavour will be.

The more general culinary term (although it's not a common one) for confectionery with a hard decorative outer shell is a [dragée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag%C3%A9e). The 'stones' in the video could be sugared almonds, although they look too small in my opinion, or something like coated raisins or other nuts.